# How to expand out a cron script to run manually

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is my cron script (a portion of):

```
CUSER=tim
APPDIR=/var/www/testing
APPVENV=/var/www/testing/ven
cat > $APPDIR/cronfile << EOF
PWD=$APPDIR/$CUSER
PATH=$APPVENV/bin:\$PATH
0 2 * * * testapp search newsite
EOF
crontab $APPDIR/cronfile
```

It seems to work but I'm really confused about how I would try to run this manually. What does this expand to if I wanted to run it from a command from shell?

I tried something like this but it didn't work :(

```
cd /var/www/testing/ven 
testapp search newsite
```

Comment: why don't you look at `/var/www/test/cronfile`, which is where the generated cron "script" will be going?

Comment: That's not a cron script. This is a shell script that writes a file which is then installed via `crontab`. That being said it is also an incorrect shell script as the assignment lines appear to be incorrect.

Comment: @MarcB The contents in that file is exactly as it is above. I still don't know how to run it.

Comment: @EtanReisner Right, ok I think I misunderstood. Can you help me understand what is wrong about it?

Comment: You don't assign to shell variables with `$` you use `var=something`. You get the value back with `$`: `echo "$var"`.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry. I wrote it by hand so that is a typo.

Comment: And the command being run by cron is `testapp search newsite` presumably while in the `/var/www/testing/tim` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
PATH=$APPVENV/bin:\$PATH
```

There should not be a backslash in there.

Manually would be:

```
cd /var/www/testing/tim
PATH=/var/www/testing/ven/bin:$PATH 
testapp search newsite
```